# Conflicting scripts, what's the issue?

Tags: javascript

I use 2 different scripts on a webpage - one pure JS, the other jQuery.

The JS script is used for toggling the hamburger menu in mobile view. **hamb.onclick** shows the menu when clicking on hamburger, **menuL.onclick** hides the menu when clicking on a menu item. The latter refuses to work when the jQuery script is active (it works when the jQuery script is commented out).

```
<script>
(function () {

    function hasClass(elem, className) {
        return new RegExp(' ' + className + ' ').test(' ' + elem.className + ' ');
    }

    function toggleClass(elem, className) {
        var newClass = ' ' + elem.className.replace(/[\t\r\n]/g, ' ') + ' ';
        if (hasClass(elem, className)) {
            while (newClass.indexOf(' ' + className + ' ') >= 0) {
                newClass = newClass.replace(' ' + className + ' ', ' ');
            }
            elem.className = newClass.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
        } else {
            elem.className += ' ' + className;
        }
    }

    var hamb = document.querySelector('.hamburger');
    var menuL = document.querySelector('.menuList');

    hamb.onclick = function () {
        toggleClass(this, 'hamburgerOpen');
        toggleClass(menuL, 'menuActive');
    };

    menuL.onclick = function () {
        toggleClass(hamb, 'hamburgerOpen');
        toggleClass(menuL, 'menuActive');
    };
})();
</script>
```

The jQuery is used for smooth navigation/scrolling to the anchors of the page:

```
<script>
    function scrollNav() {
        $('.menu a').click(function(){
            //Toggle Class
            $(".active").removeClass("active");
            $(this).closest('li').addClass("active");
            var theClass = $(this).attr("class");
            $('.'+theClass).parent('li').addClass('active');
            //Animate
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top - 160
            }, 800);
            return false;
            });
        $('.scrollTop a').scrollTop();
    }
    scrollNav();
</script>
```

As i understand it, the jQuery script highjacks the onclick event of the JS script, because they work on the same parent element: ".menu a" and "menuList" (which is the "ul" inside ".menu").

What can i do to get both scripts working together? I'm a beginner and my JavaScript skills are still weak.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: Not at all. It's as if **menuL.onclick** doesn't happen at all. (Tried with an alert message - nothing happens.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the second script hijacks the event, just move the function into the second script and run it there.

It works!